# Current through an inductor

Tags: inductance

Assume we have an inductor with the following values:
$$B=B_0 \cdot sin(2\cdot \pi \cdot f \cdot t)$$
$$N=10$$
$$r=5cm$$
$$B_0 = 2mT$$
$$f=50Hz$$
$$R=5 \Omega $$
How much current runs through the inductor as function of time?
Well I don't know the inductance, so I tried this:
$$U=-\frac{d \phi}{dt}$$ 
$$\phi = B \cdot A = 2mT \cdot sin(\pi \cdot 100 \cdot t) \cdot \pi \cdot (2\cdot10^{-2})$$ 
$$U = -\frac{d}{dt} 2mT \cdot sin(\pi \cdot 100 \cdot t) \cdot \pi \cdot (2\cdot10^{-2})^2 $$
$$U = -\frac{d}{dt} 8 \cdot \pi \cdot 10^{-7}T \cdot sin(\pi \cdot 100 \cdot t) $$
$$U = -8 \cdot \pi \cdot 10^{-7}T \cdot \frac{d}{dt} sin(\pi \cdot 100 \cdot t) $$
$$U = -8 \cdot \pi \cdot 10^{-7}T \cdot 100\cdot \pi \cdot cos(\pi\cdot 100\cdot t) $$
$$U = -800 \cdot \pi^2 \cdot 10^{-7}T \cdot cos(\pi\cdot 100\cdot t) $$ 
$$I=\frac{U}{R}= - \frac{800 \cdot \pi^2 \cdot 10^{-7}T \cdot cos(\pi\cdot 100\cdot t)}{5\Omega} = -1.579\cdot 10^{-4}\cdot cos(\pi\cdot 100\cdot t)A$$

I never saw something like that anywhere else so I'm a bit unconfident if this approach was really correct. Is this correct? Is there maybe another (easier) approach?

**Additional information:**
After reading the comments I should add some more information.
As you may have thought, this is an exercise. Here is the full text:
A coil with *N* turns is brought into a magnetic field. The area of the coil is perpendicular to the field. The coil has a radius *r* and the field changes after [see *B* above]. The coil has a resistance of *R*.
Biot-Savart was discussed but is explicitly not necessary. 
Solivng this task should be pretty easy, so I get the feeling that this task either lacks some values or I misunderstood it.

Comment: \${\displaystyle \Phi _{\mathbf {B} }=LI}\$  You must compute L https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductor#Inductance_formulas  using B

Comment: Thank you! I know this formula. How can I compute L without the length of the coil? As you can see, I know N but not the length.

Comment: Make assumptions using N,r and R It must be something like AWG40 for R =5

Comment: Just a question: How do you think the Biot-Savart law might apply? Or do you think it would, at all?

Comment: @jonk I added some more information.